# NSManagedObjectContext does not see changes ("hasChanges" always false)

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have what I thought is a very simple setup using core data: one `NSManagedObjectContext` and two `NSFetchedResultsController`s. The app has its own subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

What I do is more or less the following (pseudo code/flow):

```
1. create an NSFetchRequest
    -> with it an NSFetchedResultsController
       (and attach an NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate)
2. fetch the objects from the store
3. create another NSFetchRequest (in/from/with the same context)
    -> with it a second NSFetchedResultsController
4. fetch a subset of objects
5. change an object via
    [[[secondFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:0]
            setWhateverSyncedProperty:differentValue]
6. save the NSManagedObjectContext (-> no error)
7. restart app -> changes lost
```

What I think I read in the documentation is that a) the first FetchedResultsController's delegate should get an `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` event and b) the NSManagedObjectContext saved the changes to the persistent store. Nothing of this happens.

I would also expect the `NSManagedObjectContext` to "see" the changes just before the save, i.e. return `YES` when I call "hasChanges" on it. It does not. This probably also is the reason for not saving anything to the persistent store: it thinks there are no changes.

Strangely enough though, when I "NSLog" the Context's contents I see the **changed** object. So the change is in memory...

Last but not least: when calling

```
[[self managedObjectContext] refreshObject:[[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:2] mergeChanges:YES];
```

the delegate gets the `didChangeObject`-message!

I have a feeling that this could be related to the "Key-Value relevant notes" under *hasChanges* in the [NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) but I don't grok the concept, I guess.

Any ideas and/or hints are greatly appreciated.

By the way: I am in iPhone simulator and on XCode 3.2.5.

Comment: Just a thought: I had a similar problem. It turned out that I was doing some database initialization at start-up, but the process was not happening in the order I thought it was. If you have any other inserts or deletes that you think are independent of this problem, you might want to reassess that.

Comment: Hmm - thanks for the input. But unfortunately no, I stripped it down to no other data manipulation. To no avail...

Comment: I'm use MagicalRecord and I has same problem because I used different `NSManagedObjectContext` objects when saving and editing. For sure, we should see offset of `NSManagedObjectContext` objects (print out)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have a strong reference to your `NSManagedObjectContext`. It sounds like you're loosing the context and the managed objects lost their context. That would explain changes not getting saved.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. I can "NSLog" the context and see the changed object(s)... So the context seems to be there. Does that not mean I have the reference? Also I get the context via a retained property.

Comment: If you're storing the `NSManagedObjectContext` in an static or an ivar and retain it then you have a reference to it. You should be good. Check if you have multiple contexts. Maybe you're changing objects in one context and saving another one? You can see what context an object is in through its `-managedObjectContext` method.

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me before. make sure your properties are `@dynamic` and not `@synthesize`