# Swift 3 Xcode 8: CoreData self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges returns false

Tags: xcode, core-data

I've been following [this guide](http://resistancelabs.com/cocoa-bindings-with-nsarraycontroller-nstableview-core-data-and-swift-2-0-on-mac-os-x/).

And I ported it to my code, I have the folders being made in my library folder, the file contained is a size of "0 Bytes". Inside my tableView I am able to click and add/delete items. So it does have a connection to CoreData. However when I wish to save the results of the tableview, it steps right over the line. I put a breakpoint in and cannot see the variable (nor what I'm supposed to be looking for).

I've been trying for two days to tackle this now. I've read up on google, was using these as a reference, and still no luck. My code and bindings matches up with the sample code provided.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826967/nsmanagedobjectcontext-does-not-see-changes-haschanges-always-false)

any ideas? things to check that I haven't already done? It does seem like a link "disappeared" but everything is all on the same viewcontroller which is what is confusing me.

Comment: might I add. the only thing different on this code is it is in a tabbed view controller. So it isn't referencing the main appdelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Right Click under delegate and the saveAction will be visible. Link it to your button. Voila! nOOb mistake. Learning here!